# I am trying to pass information over from a mysql/php table to a modal window

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a standard mysql table and I call it with php that displays say 5 rows of information from the database.

Then in every row there is a link that will open the modal window. I would like the ID to go with it so I can open a new query inside the modal windows to display additional information on that person from the table where the link was.

I have read the guides and answers about modal info using jquery but I just cant get it to work.

I got so far that I actually got the id through and I could see it and that worked but I could not figure out how to use that in the mysql query.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read. Adding some code showing your problem would also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="test.php?person=1" class="modal-load">Test</a>
<div id="modal-window"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".modal-load").click(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#modal-window").load(url);
  return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
#modal-window{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

Then reference the ID sent using `$_GET['person']` on your resulting page, for instance:

```
$person = $_GET['person'];
// Use something like this to sanitize the data depending on how you connect to the database:
// $person = mysqli_escape_string($db, $person);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE person='$person'";
// Run the SQL query, show your result on the page
```

Remember that a modal window is just loading a PHP file. So get the PHP file working independently using your GET parameters and you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes thats basicly where i ended up as well. but when i opened the modal i would like a mysql query to happen to display the rest of the information from the specific ID from that link in the first table. I dont know how to take the information from the script and add it into the query

Comment: Okay. So from this code, you can style `#modal-window` to your liking.

Comment: that link opens a new page and takes me away from the whole thing i was trying to do! or i am totally stupid and dont understand the whole thing!